# how to get value from dynamically added combobox in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wpf

I want get the data from combobox in WPF.

below is mu sample code.

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbCompanies" Height="110" Width="560" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  SelectionChanged="cmbCompanies_SelectionChanged">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
```

my code-behind is:

to bind  the data to combobox:

```
 JArray companies = (JArray)response["data"];
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(companies.Count);
            if (companies.Count == 0)
            {
                // alert no compaies associated with this account.
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(companies);


                for (int i = 0; i < companies.Count; i++)
                {

                    Companies com = new Companies();
                    com.Id = (string)companies[i]["id"];
                    com.Name = (string)companies[i]["name"];

                    cmbCompanies.Items.Add(com);

                }
```

to get the data:

```
private void cmbCompanies_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //     string text = (e.AddedItems[0] as ComboBoxItem).Content as string;
            string item = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString();


            string tmp = (cmbCompanies.SelectedValue as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString();


        }
```

I am trying the above code but i am getting the any values, please help on  this.

Comment: Why is this tagged all over ASP.NET?

Comment: I have a disclaimer for such questions: WPF/UWP and XAML are designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. While you can use other approaches, doing so misses about 90% of it's power and runs into issues at every other corner. In MVVM, all the real operations happens in the ViewModel. The UI is merely a representation of those values. A comboBox would represent something like a Enum, with the selection being the currentValue. Binding will keep the ViewModel and View side values matched. There is no "retreiving" of that information beyond binding.

Comment: Also, why are you using a custom type like `JArray`? Why not a simple `J[]` or other generic collection of J's?

Answer (score 0):

Do some reading about Data Binding in WPF.  Create an object to be used as a ViewModel. Inside of the ViewModel add a property of a collection type (Observablecollection works). Bind the ItemsSource property of the ComboBox to your collection. Anything you add to your collection from now on will appear in your ComboBox

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `SelectedItem` property to a `Companies` object:

```
private void cmbCompanies_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Companies selectedCompany = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as Companies;
    if (selectedCompany != null)
    {
        string id = selectedCompany.Id;
        string name = selectedCompany.Name;
    }
}
```